# Python Pandas Applying Reverse Geocoding Function to All Columns Takes Too Long?

Tags: python, pandas, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to reverse-geocode 4 columns into location names using this library.
https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder
code is working but even for 20 lines it takes around 30 seconds,i have more than 100.000 lines so it takes forever.I wonder why it is happening ?

Example data

```
pickup_longitude pickup_latitude dropoff_longitude dropoff_latitude
-73.982155 40.767937 -73.964630 40.765602
-73.981049 40.744339 -73.973000 40.789989
```

Result:

```
 pickup_longitude pickup_latitude dropoff_longitude dropoff_latitude pickup_district dropoff_district
    -73.982155 40.767937 -73.964630 40.765602 Manhattan Manhattan
    -73.981049 40.744339 -73.973000 40.789989 Long Island City Manhattan
```

Code:

```
ds['pickup_district'] = ds.apply(lambda row: rg.search((row['pickup_latitude'],row['pickup_longitude']))[0]['name'],axis=1)
ds['dropoff_district'] = ds.apply(lambda row: rg.search((row['dropoff_latitude'],row['dropoff_longitude']))[0]['name'],axis=1)
```

plus basmadan geçmeyin sincaplar ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current structure is calling the `rg.search` method once for each row in your `DataFrame`.

It would be more efficient to create a list of tuples first, then call `rg.search` once for dropoff, and once for pickup. For example:

```
pickup_coords = ds[['pickup_latitude', 'pickup_longitude']].apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
dropoff_coords = ds[['dropoff_latitude', 'dropoff_longitude']].apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist()

pickup_results = rg.search(pickup_coords, mode=2)
ds['pickup_district'] = [x['name'] for x in pickup_results]

dropoff_results = rg.search(dropoff_coords, mode=2)
ds['dropoff_district'] = [x['name'] for x in dropoff_results]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the library with all locations at once. E.g:

```
pickups = list(zip(ds.pickup_latitude, ds.pickup_longitude))
dropoffs = list(zip(ds.dropoff_latitude, ds.dropoff_longitude))

pickup_locations = rg.search(pickups)
dropoff_locations = rg.search(dropoffs)

ds['pickup_district'] = [p["name"] for p in pickup_locations]
ds['dropoff_district'] = [d["name"] for d in dropoff_locations]
```

This is much faster than calling for each row (as apply does).